# Git-SVN clear auth-cache

Tags: git, authentication, caching, git-svn

How do I get git-svn to forget the svn authentication details ?

We have a pairing machine running windows server 2008 on which we have a git repo and we check-in to a central subversion repository. I want git to prompt me for my subversion authentication details each time I check-in.

I have removed the subversion files from under %APPDATA%\subversion\auth\svn.simple. Now whenever I use a regular subversion client I get prompted for my subversion auth but git-svn remembers the credentials still.

Is there anyway I can make it forget the authentication details?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Clear the svn authentication from **%HOMEPATH%\.subversion\auth\svn.simple**. This resets svn authentication and git prompts for a username the next time .

Note that earlier I deleted the authentication from under %appdata%\subversion\auth\svn.simple and that did not work.

Comment: %homepath% is c:\users on windows server 2008 system on which the issue is finally resolved

Answer (score 1):

You probably have another instance of subversion installed somewhere else, because git-svn doesn't remember svn authentication by itself and delegates it to subversion.

Comment: I have one tortoise svn client. No other installation. I have cleared the authentication cache of tortoise svn.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I met this problem too. The reason is "%APPDATA%\subversion\servers", this file also save your proxy username and password.