# git svn https authentication

Tags: git, svn, authentication

The [git-svn document](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) says

> --username=
>   For transports that SVN handles authentication for (http, https, and plain svn), specify the username. For other transports (eg svn+ssh://), you must include the username in the URL, eg svn+ssh://foo@svn.bar.com/project

However, in my computer (Windows 7,git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0), when I use

```
git svn clone https://server/svn/repo
```

It asks password for my windows user name first, and then (failed, since the server uses svn auth) ask the server user name and password. Everything works fine.

The problem happens when I try to clone another repo. Since this repo only available to another user, I use the following command.

```
git svn clone https://server/svn/repo1 --username xxx
```

I was expected it to ask for password but it didn't. It is simply failed with a 403 error.

I also tried to clone a third repo that available to both users, but I wanted to specify the user to be the later one,

```
git svn clone https://server/svn/repo2 --username xxx
```

It success without any password prompt. Since the passwords are different it must use the previous user credential.

Later I recognized that I shall use

```
git svn clone https://server/svn/repo2 --username=xxx
```

But it is still the same thing.

So it looks like `--username=xxx` didn't do anything. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to clear auth cache as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191025/git-svn-clear-auth-cache ?

Comment: I didn't... Let me try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for Sergey's prompt. It actually works after I cleared the subversion credential cache (**%HOMEPATH%\.subversion\auth\svn.simple**).

However I don't know why it was designed this way -- I would expect an explicit "--username" parameter shall override any thing in the credential cache. Maybe this is just a bug?